# Does Allah swt refer to himself as "We" in Surah al Kahf?

Tags: allah, surah, surat-al-kahf

SA, I'm a recent revert and was listening to Surah al Kahf on youtube for the first time in a long long time and noticed that the narration uses "We." Is the narration in Surah al Kahf from Allah swt using "We" or from Angels speaking on behalf of Allah swt. Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: This IMO needs more focus as we was used in surat al-Kahf many times in different contexts. You should specify which "we" you are actually referring to. We can't say that we by default refers to Allah as stated in the posted answer.

Comment: In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04go_B1bVNY there are "We"s of the narration which refer to willing/causing the events of the story such as allowing the boys to sleep in the cave etc. I like this video because it has quotation marks for when the subjects/characters/non-creator speak. I was confused that the non quotation marked "We"s were there especially given that I didn't know that Arabic also had a royal "We." To answer your comment properly, I am referring to the "We" outside of quoted statements in this video.

Comment: It would be best if you gave a list of verses (or quote them) as at least in my case mostly a fire wall hinders me to listen/watch the video and verse # are easier to find than waiting for them to appear in a video.

Comment: Two examples of it are verses 7 and 8 where " wa Enna" is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bismillah hir rahman nir raheem

Wa alaykum as sallam wa rahmatullah wa baraktuhu
Yes and in many other places in quran allah refers to himself as we,this is known in the arabic and English language as when a "royal we".
Allah knows best as sallamu alaykum

Comment: Jazaj allah khayran!